# Yii CActiveDataProvider Relations

Tags: yii, cactivedataprovider

Anyone can enighten me, i am new to Yii. I have 3 tables

```
projects      (id,name,status,created_by)
users         (id,name)
project_users (id,project_id,user_id)
```

The condition is: Show all projects if created by current user or current user is a project member. I have already a working code for this.

```
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->join = ' LEFT JOIN project_users pu ON pu.project_id=t.id';
    $criteria->addCondition('created_by='.Yii::app()->user->id.' OR pu.user_id='.Yii::app()->user->id);
    $criteria->distinct = true;

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Project',
    array(
            'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>15),
            'criteria'=> $criteria
        )
    );
```

But, id like to learn how can i get same result using "WITH" (relational AR query in Yii). I already tried but all failed. Please help thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the relation on `Project` model file

```
projectUsers' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProjectUsers', array('id'=>'project_id')),
```

`$dataprovider` should be

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Project',
        array(
                'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>15),
                'criteria'=>array(
                    'with'=>array(
                        'projectUsers' => array('alias' => 'pu')
                    ),
                    'condition' => 't.created_by='.Yii::app()->user->id.' OR pu.user_id='.Yii::app()->user->id,
                    'distinct'=>true,
                    'together'=>true, 
                ),
            )
        );
```

Check out my picture. The criteria is more powerful than that, but you can understand the basically how to use

[image]

Small tip: If everything is new with you, just [enable Yii log](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9924-logging-sql-queries-while-testing/) to see what the query is produced eventually, then you can troubleshoot the problem by yourself.

Comment: it must be the missing "together" param in my code.